# Application cache manifest not loading in Firefox, ok in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-appcache

I have the following manifest

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# cache-revision-29541
# cache-creation-date: Fri Dec  5 11:33:29 GMT 2014
CACHE:
app.html
NETWORK:
*
```

And the following app.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="app.manifest">
<head>
    <title>cache test</title>
    <script>
    function checkCache() {
        var appCache = window.applicationCache;
        var logACEvent = function(e) {
            console.log("Cache Event " + e.type + " Status: " + appCache.status);
        }
        appCache.addEventListener('error', logACEvent, false);
        appCache.addEventListener('checking', logACEvent, false);
        appCache.addEventListener('noupdate', logACEvent, false);
        appCache.addEventListener('downloading', logACEvent, false);
        appCache.addEventListener('progress', logACEvent, false);
        appCache.addEventListener('updateready', logACEvent, false);
        appCache.addEventListener('cached', logACEvent, false);
    }
    checkCache();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And my .htaccess entries (to set content type)

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
```

I have verified the server is setting the content type.

In Safari, this outputs two console messages

```
Cache Event checking Status: 2
Cache Event noupdate Status: 1
```

In Chrome, this outputs

```
Cache Event checking Status: 2
Cache Event noupdate Status: 1
```

In Firefox I get

```
Cache Event checking Status: 0
Cache Event error Status: 0
```

In IE11 I get

```
(i) Resource doesn’t exist on the server: 'http://10.119.103.2/~adf/RMC2/release/beta/app.html'.
(i) AppCache Fatal Error
Cache Event error Status: 0
```

The app URL is 'http://{host}/~adf/RMC2/release/beta/app.html'
app.manifest and app.html are in the same folder.

No indication of what the error might be. I can load the URL that IE complains about directly (its the same URL used to load the app).

about:cache in firefox does not even list this application.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
app.html
```

Even with the above simple manifest, IE11 and Firefox are reporting an error, with IE reporting a Manifest parse failure error in the console.

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
File: app.html
Creating AppCache with manifest: 'http://10.119.103.2/~adf/RMC2/release/beta/app.manifest'.
Cache Event checking Status: 0
Manifest parsing failure: 'http://10.119.103.2/~adf/RMC2/release/beta/app.manifest'.
AppCache Fatal Error
Cache Event error Status: 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update:

If I install app.manifest and app.html in ~adf/RMC2/... it works in all browsers, its when it is installed in the sub-folders release/beta that it doesn't work in firefox and IE.

Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured this out eventually with the help Firefox's built in appcache validate tool.

```
Shift+F2
appcache validate
```

This indicated that the server was sending no-store headers for the resources, which is in conflict with them being in the application cache.

Removed the offending entries from .htaccess on the server and the cache started working.

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar issue. Using `appcache validate` you get a useful message back on what's wrong. In my case I had uploaded my files via FTP. But as the cache.manifest file was uploaded before some of the cached files, Firefox complained that some of the cached files where newer than the cache.manifest file. Solution for me was to upload all files, then wait 10 sec, then upload cache.manifest again. You don't believe it...